# Cell Editor params get empty when applying value formatters

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, react-typescript, ag-grid-react

I have the following code

```
function findName(v:number){
     const found = permissionLevelArray.find((item:{name:string,value:number}) => 
      item.value === v);
     return found?.name || "";
 }
const [columnDefs] = useState([
  { 
    field: 'status',
    colId:'status', 
    rowGroup: true, hide: true ,
  },
  {
    field: 'firstName',
    colId:'firstName',
  },
  {
    field: 'lastName',
    colId:'lastName',
  },
  {
    field: 'emailAddress',
    colId:'emailAddress',
  },
  {
    field: 'permissionLevelID',
    colId:'permissionLevelID',
    // enables editing
    editable:(params:any) => params.data.status === "Unselected",
    cellEditor:"agRichSelectCellEditor",
    cellEditorParams: {
      values: permissionLevelArray.map((item:{value:Number,name:string}) => item.name),
    },
    cellEditorPopup: true,
    valueFormatter: (params:any) => {
      return params.data && params.data.status === "Selected" ? findName(params.data.permissionLevelID): "";
    } 

  },
]);
```

so I have grouped data into **selected** and **unselected users**
selected users are not editable. unselected ones are editable.

Problem:
the **unselected ones are editable** but the **params** get **empty** resulting in an empty drop down on click.